# I am unable to find 'AGE' from given DOB '2001-11-24 00:00:00' using below python code

Tags: python

```py
v1 = 2001-11-24 00:00:00  (I am getting this value for a print statement)

def age(birthdate):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthdate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthdate.month, birthdate.day))
    return age
print(age(date(v1)), "years")
```

ERROR:

```
print(age(date(v1)), "years")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Please suggest solution

Comment: your code does not run as it is. Please provide a full stack trace and a [mre]. It is difficult to know what exactly is going wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous errors in your code:
v1 needs to be a string. There is no function date() as you assume: this will cause a `NameError`. The line beginning `age=` does not make sense as it subtracts a True or False value. You need to convert date strings to Python datetime before manipulation. It is not a good idea to use the same name (age) for a function and a variable within. Your code as given will not run nor give the error message you state; there must be something missing

Try this approach:

```
from datetime import datetime

v1 = "2001-11-24 00:00:00"

def age(birthdate):
    today = datetime.today()
    the_age = (today - birthdate).days/(365.25) 
    return the_age

d =  datetime.strptime(v1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(round(age(d), 2), "years")
```

gives

```
21.72 years
```